# Rails 4, create multiple objects - how to permit it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

How to permit this parameters:

```
contacts: [ 
    {:value => 'value', :contacts_type => 'contact_type'}, 
    {:value => 'value', :contacts_type => 'contact_type'}, 
]
```

To create many objects by controller action in one JSON request?

Answer (score 3):

Like below, `contacts` will be an array of resources with specific attributes `value` and `contacts_type`:

```
params.permit(contacts: [:value, :contacts_type])
```

Comment: So how 'create' method should look like? If I just using `company.contacts.create(contacts_params)` it returns error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: contacts)`

Comment: @kuatro add `attr_accessor :contacts` to your model class. It shall work.

Comment: @AlokAnand adding attr_accessor :contacts will create the record with nil values

Answer (score 0):

If you get params like the following:--

```
:params=>{:xyz => {:contacts => [{:value => 'value', :contacts_type => 'type'}, ..]}}
```

Then do the folowing:--

```
params.require(:xyz).permit(contacts: [:value, :contacts_type])
```

And add `attr_accessor :contacts` to your model if `contacts` is just a form field name part.

Answer (score 0):

Work around for this should be

```
def contact_params
   new_params = params.permit(contacts: [:value, :contacts_type])
   new_params[:contacts] if new_params
end
```

Please suggest alternate solution if any